# ASP.NET RemoteAttribute validates model on all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model `User`, in this class I used `[Remote]` attribute to validate field `UserId`. I have used the same model in 2 different pages. The validation works for both pages, however I want to turn Remote validation off for one particular page. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no postback in `asp.net-mvc`. Show us some code.

Comment: I mean when click on submit button in login page, there is a page submit,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different model for login page. That would be the most natural approach.